# Using Vector Drawable Compat

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I am making an android app with a few fragments. In one of these fragments, I have a toolbar with a back arrow as an image button.
In the XML File, I have the "app:srcCompat" attribute, but I get an error when using this attribute saying this: "To use VectorDrawableCompat, you need to set 'android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true'

[image]

Comment: Well... it already tells you the solution! `To use VectorDrawableCompat, you need to set 'android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true'`

Comment: I have the same problem, didn't do the suggested solution but everything works on old and new devices. I would like to know why this warning keeps appearing if they don't seem to affect anything.

Comment: @ModularSynth For newbies, it isn't clear where this is supposed to be added, let alone how.

Answer (score 114):

In your module `build.gradle` file, you need to add this line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true // This line here
    }
    ...
}

...
```

Comment: what if it's already added but still getting the "error/warning"

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat try syncing your project again

Answer (score 11):

add this line to your Gradle file under `defaultConfig` block:

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

Also, you need to add this block of code in every activity or fragment where you're referencing drawables instead of images in `srcCompat`:

```
static {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` this line of code in you app level build.gradle inside the `defaultConfig` tag

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your package Name"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"
        //This is the Main Line you have to add to avoid this warning.
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following line

```
android:src="@drawable/edit"
```

Answer (score -18):

Add to your ImageButton:

```
tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat"
```

Comment: Ignoring problem is not a solution