# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I found this error on my crashlytics and i don't know what the problem is.
So by just looking to the code i thought it could be something with one of the images.

So by researching i realized it could be one of these two things: I put the image in drawable-24 and it should be in drawable folder. So i checked and all the images are in the drawable folder. Then i thought it could be because i should use app:srcCompat instead of android:src. The problem is if i changed the gradle file to use this, it would affect the entire module and i would get the error :  `When using VectorDrawableCompat, you need to use app:srcCompat`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Vector Drawable Compat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226382/using-vector-drawable-compat)

Comment: But if i use this, i will get this error everywhere i use android:src : When using VectorDrawableCompat, you need to use `app:srcCompat`. Is this just a warning or my app will crash eventually?